# Template parameter pack of mixed templated types (std::function recreation with optional arguments)

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to make an std::function alternative that supports optional arguments with defaults. I tried a few different syntactical ideas, but the most realistic seems to be a parameter pack of specialised templates that hold argument data. Here's my desired outer syntax:

```
Function<
    void /*Return type*/,
    Arg<false, int> /*Required int parameter*/,
    Arg<true, bool, true> /*Optional bool parameter that defaults to true*/
> func;
```

I would have liked to maintain the `Function<ReturnType(args)>` syntax but it appears you can only put typenames in parentheses and not classes. Here's my current code:

```
template<bool Optional, typename Type, Type Default>
class Arg;

template<typename Type, Type Default>
class Arg<false, Type, Default> {};

template<typename Type, Type Default>
class Arg<true, Type, Default> {};
```

Problem 1: I can't find a way to make the "Default" parameter non-required for the `false` specialisation. I've tried proxy classes with a default constructor, changing the third argument to a pointer and with specifying nullptr (which isn't really ideal syntactically), and a const reference to a type (which still requires three arguments from the user side) but nothing seems to allow two arguments to be accepted with `Function<false, Type>`.

Problem 2: I can't find the right syntax to get a parameter pack of mixed template argument types. I've tried (obviously invalid syntax)

```
template<typename RetType, Arg<bool, typename Type, Type>... args>
class Function{};
```

and even a double/nested template but I can't make this work either.

All of this indirection really steams from the fact that you can't have multiple parameter packs in a class template so I have to find creative ways to specify optional arguments, but I will take any solution I can get to somehow making this function at compile-time and not having to construct these functions dynamically.

I'm using C++20.

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to achieve. What is wrong with `std::function<R(Args...)>`?

Comment: Can you please add some use case, e.g. as user code, which uses your code? I am unclear what you really want to achieve what is not already part of std::function and lambdas. XY problem?

Comment: @L.F. std::function doesn't allow for optional arguments, as in you can't replicate headers like ``void func(int a, bool b = true);`` and have to always call the function with a second boolean parameter.

Comment: @code-gs You can use `[](int a) { return func(a); }`.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with C++ lambdas so I'll take a look at that solution

Answer (score 1):

To make the third template argument optional when the first argument is `false`, you can use a default argument with a `std::enable_if`:

```
template <bool Optional, typename T,
    T Default = std::enable_if_t<!Optional, T>{}>
class Arg;
```

This way, `Arg<false, int>` is equivalent to `Arg<false, int, 0>`, whereas `Arg<true, int>` is ill-formed.

---

You can use generic arguments:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Function {
    static_assert(std::conjunction_v<is_arg_v<Args>...>);
};
```

Where `is_arg` can be something as simple as

```
template <typename T>
struct is_arg :std::false_type {};
template <bool Optional, typename T, T Default>
struct is_arg<Arg<Optional, T, Default>> :std::true_type {};
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_arg_v = is_arg<T>::value;
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make this support classes without a default constructor? Say something like
``struct A { A() = delete; A(int) {} }; Function<false, A> func;``

Comment: @code-gs What should be the value of `Default` then?

Comment: I'd like it to be nothing for functions marked as a required argument, but I suppose without template polymorphism that isn't possible.